# How to deal with a variety of GUI layout questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Is there any consensus about how to deal with questions that ask about how to achieve a certain GUI layout?

I personally observe this in the [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) and [layout-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/layout-manager) tags, but can imagine that this similarly applies to similar GUI frameworks, even web-based ones, and probably even down to CSS:

A user wants to arrange a certain set of GUI components in a certain manner. The questions can be well-written, well-stated, maybe even including a MVCE or a nice mockup image of the desired outcome. And a well-stated question can receive a proper answer.

But there are infinitely many layouts, and many of the questions may be of very limited use for future readers. And of course, it is not possible to sensibly write a *canonical answer* for GUI layout questions.

Note that I don't see this as an immediate problem right now, and therefore, this is tagged as [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion): There will probably not be one acceptable answer. But maybe we can gather some opinions and criteria about how handle this sort of question - i.e. when to answer it, and when to close.

For example, one could argue about the *specificity* of the question: There are high-level "canonical" questions, e.g. about [how to do a 3 column layout HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566660/3-column-layout-html-css). And there may be low-level, specific questions about how to make the bottom border of a cell in a Swing `JTable` one pixel wider. Both can be equally justified. The first ones by their generic applicability. The other ones by their specificity, requiring "expert knowledge" (and where could you find this, if not on stack overflow?).

But I wonder about how to determine whether a "GUI layout question" is really worth being answered. For example: At which point would it be more appropriate to add one of the (nowadays somewhat discouraged) "RTFM" comments, pointing to the [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) (or a similar site for other UI frameworks), and then vote to close?

<sup>(Even if I wasn't sure which *reason* I could state for the vote...)</sup>

Comment: As with design patterns in code, there are also UI patterns that are common either to apps within a specific platform, or even across different platforms (e.g. information "cards" between which you swipe back and forth are a pattern that's common to many touch-based UIs). I think a question asking how to implement such a pattern on a specific platform given specific constraints, and code showing an existing approach that's been taken, is appropriate for the site.

Comment: @BoltClock Sure, as I said: Common use cases and "template-like" solutions can be of *huge* value for many future readers. Similarly, questions about highly specific quirks of certain UI frameworks can have their justification. The question is rather about whether "I want a website with three columns", "...four columns", "...four columns and a header", "...three columns and a fixed menu" should be accepted (this is overly suggestive, to get the point across). At some point, one *has* to say: "Read something about CSS and do it on your own!". Where is this point?

Comment: So you want a close reason analogous to 'too broad' -- like 'too narrow'? Too narrow to be of use to anyone in the future? An awful lot of questions could arbitrarily fall in this bucket (eg a lot of regex).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Yes, RegEx questions might suffer from the same effect, but note that "too narrow" is not the actual reason here: Even a very narrow question can be a great question, namely when it is "unique" in some way. But for UI layouts (or regex, for that matter) there is an arbitrary number of (arbitrarily) similar questions, sounding out the definition of being a "duplicate". In doubt, a gold-badge-user could decide whether something really has a unique aspect, or whether it is just another slight variation in a cluster of similar questions, but it's very difficult...

Comment: That's a difficult question, as sometimes it's as simple as directing the user to a suitable tutorial or even a possibly duplicate question.  Other times it's about providing a suggested workflow, processes and habits which can be used by the OP so they can resolve the issue themselves. Personally, I try to avoid a "single" answer and demonstrate that the solution can be solved through a number of different techniques. In some case there is not enough context to solve the problem in its entirety, sometimes, there is too much. As we with all questions - a learning path is preferred - IMHO

Comment: I think any answer will be a result of the quality of the question.  If the OP has made an effort to solve the issue themselves, then it's question worth investing in, if all they do is post a picture and say "I want to do that", then all they'll get is a high level over view of "how" it might be achieved and bunch of links to suitable tutorials - but I'm mean like that  

Comment: Depending on how high level we are talking, we commonly see UI queries posted on [https://ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com) so maybe they need to be flagged as Off-Topic and redirected here instead?

Comment: A lot of questions in SO are for a very specific needs. They perhaps may not be useful for other readers. If we go about closing such questions, we'll end up closing a big percentage of questions.

Comment: One thing is sure: the tag [tag:geometry] should not be used for GUI layouts

Comment: @sid-m Again, because it's important: This is not about the *specificity* of the question. It's rather about *what makes* the question specific, and how similar other questions are. Overly suggestive: "How to make a website layout with 3 columns?" and "How to make a website with a fixed header?" are fine. But what if the question "How to make 3 columns and a fixed header?" pops up? It's certainly specific, and there *might* be caveats that make this question worth being answered, but likely, the answer could be "Just combine the code snippets from `this` and `that` answer"...