# Is this plagiarism or a simple bad answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, plagiarism

Let's consider this off-topic question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56982855/8620333

The user is asking how to create a hover effect similar to a one they saw in a website. They probably don't know that we can easily get HTML/CSS code from any page.

Another user posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56982989/8620333) with the relevant code that they copied from the site with 0 details. A simple copy/paste with no changes.

Does this answer deserve a flag for plagiarism? For me it's a clear **yes** but since they posted the code that the OP is looking for, it's probably a *valid bad* answer?

Of course, the whole question should not exist and should be deleted but my concern is: should I flag such an answer or simply downvote it and wait until the question is deleted?

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but where did op copy that code from? If you mean the link in the answer itself, then it's highly likely that the answer author also wrote that code. User here is called "Sonia", user on the other page "Soniaj204".

Comment: @BDL from the website posted in the question. There is a button in the site having this hover effect. You can inspect the code and get it

Comment: @BDL the OP created that pen after getting the code from the site. I am not talking about the copy from that link but rather a copy from the website to create the pen and post an answer

Comment: Seems like plain plagiarism to me, plus probable copyright violation (there's no copyright notice on the CSS file, but in most jurisdictions it'd still be a violation). CSS and plagiarism/copyright is a bad scene though, it's widespread since clients often ask _do it like this_, and you can easily view and copy the code. Still, seems valid to remove it from SO for that reason.

Comment: @ErikA "*there's no copyright notice*" probably worth a reminder here that you don't *need* a copyright notice for copyright to be in effect. It's not opt-in, but opt-out - an author automatically has copyright on all their work unless explicitly given away in some way.

Comment: *"...should I flag such an answer or simply downvote it [...] ?"* Do not (only) downvote an answer if you think plagiarism may be involved. Downvotes are for showing disagreement with the quality, efficacy, clarity, correctness or whatever other property of the answer itself. Plagiarism is very serious: **always** mod flag if you believe you found one.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado That's good to know. I haven't been around much, so I didn't know the correct downvote/flag lingo either.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes I regularly flag a lot of Plagiarism but in this case I wasn't really sure since it's an edge case of an answer showing the *code* that the OP failed to extract himself.

Comment: @TemaniAfif But you don't need to be 100% sure, that's something that the mod (or mods) can help you with. Having a suspicion is valid... you can flag like *"hello, mod, maybe I'm wrong but I reckon that there is a case of plagiarism going on here, can you check? My evidences are foo, bar and baz. Thanks"*. Then, if the mod doesn't think so, they just decline the flag. I reckon that, this way,  you err on the side of caution.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I _very_ rarely decline good-faith custom flags; they'd have to be blatantly incorrect from the user's perspective. That pretty much doesn't happen. In general, it is helpful to point out suspicious behavior or content to us, even when further investigation does not confirm any wrongdoing.

Comment: @BDL If you quote your own work without attribution, it can still count as plagiarism, apparently.

Comment: To be realistic: Most answers from this person are "code snippets with 0 details", for that matter. It seems that this is what many people are looking for. \*shakes head\*.

Comment: @Marco13 yes, another person who (unfortunately) got the trick of getting easy reputation by only posting working code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I agree that this *is* plagiarism. Copying something with/without knowing that they are allowed to copy still constitutes plagiarism. (We do get a lot of users replying to our mod messages telling "we didn't know we shouldn't copy, we will not do it from now on".)

This does seems to be in good faith, given that the answerer seems to have fixed the code for the OP. Ideally the OP should have posted the actual code in their question rather than just a link to the website with the erroneous code. (Aside, I think where we failed was that we didn't close the question before it received answers. That post is a classic case of this FAQ: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4099593). We probably should also be educating both the poster of the question and the answer about this.)

I am still in two minds over this. 20k users *can* take care of this easily by just nuking the entire post, but the problem is when there aren't enough 20k users looking at the post (or if the poster has a history of doing this). Therefore, to be on the safer side, feel free to flag these posts for plagiarism, but be clear about it in your flag that the user has copied the content from the link posted in the question. We also check the user's history and their other posts while dealing with plagiarism flags to see if the user has any other similar cases. (Usually these kinda plagiarism cases don't have much history behind them.)

Comment: to rectify something: it's not the website of the OP. The asker simply found a fancy effect in a random website and want to replicate it.

Comment: I think an important factor here is the *quantity* of code that was copied. Had the relevant code been only a few lines, I don't think it would constitute as plagiarism since you probably cannot get the desired result any other way. However, 144 lines of unedited code just pasted into an answer is an entirely different story...

Comment: Technically this isn't *plagiarism*, which is specifically *passing off a work as one's own/without proper attribution*. This is rather *theft or unauthorized use of copyrighted, trademarked, or otherwise licensed work*. The two go hand-in-hand often, but are not the same thing. What I'm more concerned about is what must surely be voting fraud for that user who got at least 3 upvotes on such an answer.

Comment: @TylerH, I am not that worried about nomenclature as such, but rather about the action. Also, there is no need to doubt the voting regularity of that particular user. The tag on the question is the largest tag on Stack Overflow and it obviously would have received more views, which would have brought in the votes. (In fact, it looks like the user was a victim of serial downvoting).

Comment: On a related note, we are getting a lot of voting fraud flags on lower rep users these days which assume that they are committing fraud just because they get a couple of upvotes. It is kinda concerning, for sure, though I've never declined any such flag.

Comment: @BhargavRao This may be beyond the scope of these comments, but my impression is (and there is a least strong evidence) that people are upvoting each other with the vague meaning of "Yeah, I could have copied+pasted the same code snippet from somewhere". (This is not meant to be *totally* dismissive. Reading 1000 pages of W3C specs vs. getting the right 3 lines of code is what can save *hours* of time, and as such, the answers *are* "useful". It's only sad to see this happening. Something's wrong out there, but I cannot point my finger at it...)

Comment: @Marco13 What's wrong in most cases is that the questions are usually not presented in a generic manner, meaning that it's unlikely someone else needing to find the specific information contained in a dense and long spec will actually find the post. This makes them useful to only the asker, which is not in line with the goal of SO to be an information repository that others can find info in. The sheer quantity of the over-specific, personalized help requests has reduced SO from a knowledge repository to something more closely approximated by a help desk.

Comment: @jpmc26 Since the Q/A discussed here was about CSS, I think that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373852/3182664 might be somewhat related, regarding the point that you mentioned (specificity vs. future use) - but it's hard or impossible to draw a line. (I think the 'Documentation' feature could be argued to have been an attempt to solve this problem (seeing 'crappy documentation' as the root cause of the problem). Bhe core of this Q/A was about the "plagiarism", so this can likely not be discussed here thoroughly)